# How do I uninstall Xtrap?

Tags: pc, drm

I seem to have a program called Xtrap on my system I have no idea how it got there, after  Googling this application it appears to be a MMO game tool but I only have one MMO on my system and it does not use Xtrap...

How do I remove it? I've tried though Windows uninstaller and CCleaner there are no entries for the program or game programs that it's associated with.

Comment: If you check the property of the program shortcut, which folder on your PC does it point to?

Comment: Xtrap is actually DRM - http://www.outspark.com/forums/showthread.php?48880-Xtrap-Things-you-should-know!

Answer (score 2):

You might have to do it in safe mode since the app may still be running (trying killing the process in task manger). Also here is a link to a uninstall site http://www.ehow.com/how_12206241_delete-xtrap.html